# USA - B2 Visitor visa for parents with Indian passports

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, tourist-visas, b2visa

I am filing a DS-160 for my mother. I appreciate insights on how the situation below can be handled.

1. Her passport has my dad's name without surname (ABC) in the last page under "spouse" section. But the name in my dad's passport (front page - given name, surname) is ABC XXX. I was thinking to fill the DS-160 as per her passport, leaving the surname blank in the section to fill spouse details, but it seems to be a mandatory field. Should I fill FNU as given name and ABC as surname for spouse? (or) Should I fill my dad's actual surname?
2. Also, my dad's first name has a spelling mistake (one additional letter) in my mom's passport. Will having an affidavit (signed by an attorney) confirming the different variations of my father's name be helpful in this scenario to avoid any visa rejections during the interview?

Comment: "Her passport has my dad's name without surname": where does it show this name -- on the main ID page under "given names" or "surname"?  On the page with additional details under "name of spouse"?  Somewhere else?  Which field of the DS-160 are you considering leaving blank?  I am voting to close as unclear; if you edit the question you add these details I will retract my vote or vote to reopen.

Comment: Edited my question. thanks for the feedback! 
I dont think so missing these details make this message unclear.
 1. My mom's passport has only field where my dad's detail present: spouse, 2. My dad passport has only fields (given name, surname) where his name would be present.